# Error with process payment in sandbox mode

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I get error.
When process form payment, I send

```
PayPal\Api\Amount::__set_state(array(
   '_propMap' => 
  array (
    'currency' => 'USD',
    'total' => '0.63',
    'details' => 
    PayPal\Api\Details::__set_state(array(
       '_propMap' => 
      array (
        'shipping' => '0.20',
        'tax' => '0.40',
        'subtotal' => '0.03',
      ),
    )),
  ),
))
```

and i get "Transaction amount details (subtotal, tax, shipping) must add up to specified amount total"

Response data:

```
"transactions": [
            {
                "amount": {
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "total": "3.60",
                    "details": {
                        "subtotal": "0.03",
                        "tax": "0.40",
                        "shipping": "0.20"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response data shows a `total` of USD 3.60 but if you added up the total of `subtotal`, `tax` and `shipping`, it is just USD 0.63.

Therefore the error message.

Even though I am not sure why your `total` in your request form looks different from the `total` in your response data.